Unable to create glass texture that I want
The effect I want to achieve:

Having glossy shading line (red highlight):

I have tried out with transparent node, and just glass node, it doesn't really works to get the effect I want. Also tried different lighting such as HDRI and spot lighting, I can't get rid of the weird shading of the bottle
Last 2 pics to rule out that it is mesh or texture assign issue:


Any idea how I can fix this?

You probably want a low Roughness. Also you may want to add more things in the environment to have more things to reflect.

I always use a simple Principled BSDF with very low roughness (not 0 because that is unrealistic) and Transmission > Weight set to 1. The rest is just creating environment or having a good HDRI and making sure the Max Bounces are enough (especially Glossy and Transmission). The glossy shading line will not be achieved with a ridiculously high Roughness > 100%, in reality they have bright light screens etc. for things like that. More about the bounce settings in my answer here: Glass render is black for some reason

The actual coke bottle has a lot of character to the glass - it's more complex than a round bottle, it has a lot of contour.

@AllenSimpson Yep, that's another point. The question says "the effect I want to achieve" without specifying what effect exactly and where to make compromises. Because to get the same look like the reference the bottle needs the same design features to get reflections in the same areas and you have to recreate a similar studio environment and lighting setup.
